# regexp finding string with some letter inside quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

i am trying write regexp for this string:

```
<path transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,697.323)" d="M 116.863 635.155 L 204.375 635.155 L 204.375 652.163 L 116.863 652.163 Z " fill="#fedbb4AA"/>
```

i need find string like this if inside of d has L letter 3 times, i writing something like:

```
d="(.*?)(\sL\s){3}.*?"
```

but it doesn't work how i expected

Comment: I think like this `d="(?:[^L"]*L){3}[^L"]*"` https://regex101.com/r/vAc5jT/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern that you tried does not work for the example data, because you only repeat the second group 3 times `(\sL\s){3}` which would match a string with doubled whitespace chars between the L like `L  L  L`

If you would repeat it as a whole group `d="(?:.*?\sL\s){3}.*?"` it could possibly match too much. The `.` can also match `"` and matching 3 times an L can pass over the closing `"`

---

What you could do is to repeat 3 times matching any char except a `"` or `L`

```
d="(?:[^L"]*L){3}[^L"]*"
```

The pattern matches

- `d="`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^L"]*L` Match 0+ times any chat except `L` or `"`
- `){3}` Close the group and repeat 3 times
- `[^L"]*` Match 0+ times any char except `L` or `"`
- `"` Match the closing `"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y7XGpa/1)

If there has to be a whitespace char before and after the `L`

```
d="(?:[^L"]*\sL\s){3}[^L"]*"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uyz4oK/1)